# I want to load multiple sound source files with kotlin soundPool

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an android application with kotlin, referring to the following article.

https://akira-watson.com/android/kotlin/soundpool-play.html

What I want to do is create about 50 buttons and I want to make a different sound from each button in the sound pool.

I think that if I can write it in a loop statement, I can write it concisely When loading a sound source

```
soundOne = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.one, 1)
```

Of this part
Is it possible to use **"R.raw.one"** as a variable and substitute the file name of the sound source there?

In addition, the button on-click event `button1.setOnClickListener`
Of this part
Is it possible to turn "button1" with a *for statement*, etc.?

Comment: Are you adding 50 buttons dynamically ?

Comment: thanks your reply.
no its Statically.